# Resharper 9.0 says 'No tests found in selected solution items.' Yet there are over 100 tests

Tags: nunit, ncover, unit-testing, resharper-9.0

Resharper 9.0 says 'No tests found in selected solution items.'  Yet there are over 100 tests.

I right click my solution in Visual Studio 2013 and click the "Run Unit Tests" option near the bottom of the context menu.  I get the error message: "No tests found in selected solution items.".

Every once in a while, they do show up and run, but most of the time, they don't show up and I get the error message.

I have NCover installed and it has a 'Bolt Tests' tab from which I can run all the tests.  However, I would prefer to run the tests from the main menu using Resharper.

Does anybody know why these tests aren't showing up and how to get them to consistently be discovered?

Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: I'm having the same issue but since I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Preview, I thought that was the reason. But at least this rules out VS as the cause. It seems like Resharper is not able to figure out what tests are in the solution. And I also get intermittent runs where it doesn't find any tests. I am also having some other weird issues where the left bar in which the Run Unit Test icon exists keeps disappearing.

Comment: I noticed this issue too. However, as soon as you open a file that contains unit tests, the "run unit tests" command will find the tests from this file, but still won't find the others... Definitely a bug in R# 9

Comment: I don't know if you've already applied Resharper 9 Update 1 (apparently dated December 19th, 2014), but I was getting that message before the update and I'm not getting it any more.

Comment: Yup.  Got the update. problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the latest update of 9.1 solved the problem.  Thanks everybody.

Comment: Note: 9.1 is an EAP release, not a production release

Comment: did 9.1 resharper need a separate license?

Comment: These were the Beta versions, so no license needed at the time.  I currently have updated with the latest re-sharper license.